# how to update single database from two computers

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to know how to update a database installed on two computers. I want to update only a single database. Whether I work on 1st computer or 2nd computer I want to update the database once. How can I do this?

This is my database connect method:

```
public static SqlConnection connect() {
    String conct = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\3000Apliance\3000Apliance\300Apliance.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conct);

    con.Open();
    return con;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one Computer as Server keep your database there. on other computer use sqlmanagement and connect to server computer via Ip/name 192.0.0.0/name and create a path to database.
this way you can use more then 2 computers to update database at a time. you can connect computers by peer to peer or use a switch to connect multiple computers.

your new connection string should look like this:
Data

Source    =    .    \    SQLEXPRESS;    AttachDbFilename=192.0.0.0\name\3000Apliance\3000Apliance\300Apliance.mdf;    Integrated     Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conct);